# How can I create a status bar with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a status bar, at the bottom of the screen (fixed position) for my webapp. Because I haven't lots of CSS knowledge, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.

How can I create this? I've been looking around the web, but I haven't found any example... Or is it possible to create a second nav-bar (it looks great!), and attach it to the bottom of the screen? Maybe creating some kind of "navbar-fixed-bottom" CSS rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fixed-bottom Navbar seems right. There's even a [Bootstrap Example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) that demonstrates this.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't see this example, 'cos I was searching for something like "bootstrap status bar"...

Comment: Nope, sorry, I have no idea.